# How to debug a Visual Studio Package in a VSIX created in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, vsix, visual-studio-sdk

I'm not able to debug the simplest possible VS Package in the simplest possible VSIX Project.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a VSIX project: **File / New / Project / Extensibility / VSIX Project**
2. Add Visual Studio Package: right-click the project node in Solution Explorer and select **Add / New Item / Extensibility / Visual Studio Package**
3. Open the newly created package file (`VSPackage1.cs`) and put a breakpoint on line 68, the first line of `Initialize()`, `base.Initialize()`
4. Press `F5` to start debugging

This launches an experimental instance of Visual Studio 2015, with the package installed (confirmed in **Tools / Extensions and Updates...**), but the breakpoint is disabled:

[image: breakpoint disabled]

The above steps are from the Getting Started guide (`index.html`) of a freshly created VSIX Project, so it should have worked.

Additional info:

- The solution configuration is **Debug**, platform is **Any CPU**
- The Debug properties of the project automatically have **Start external program** set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe` and **Command line arguments** set to `/rootsuffix Exp`
- I set **Copy Debug Symbols to Output Directory** to `True`, and after that the `projectname.pdb` file correctly appeared in `bin\Debug`
- The `bin\Debug\projectname.vsix` file contains `projectname.pdb`
- The project is included in **Assets** in `source.extension.vsixmanifest` with `Type=Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage`
- I tried adding the project in **Assets** in `source.extension.vsixmanifest` with `Type=Microsoft.VisualStudio.MefComponent` but that didn't seem to do much. On the first run after this, the breakpoints appeared enabled, but were not hit. On the 2nd and subsequent runs the breakpoints went back to disabled state during running.
- I tried changing the version in the manifest, but I notice any effect.
- I tried running the experimental instance separately, and attaching to it with the debugger, but that behaved the same way as when launching directly with `F5`, no difference whatsoever.
- I tried adding `Console.WriteLine` statements in the `Initialize` method, but I couldn't find the debugging texts in the `Output` window.
- I tried x86 platform instead of Any CPU, but same result.
- A colleague followed the same steps and got the same result, so it's probably not specific to my computer. (I invite anyone to please follow the same steps and prove me wrong, or to spot the mistakes in my steps.)

All this seems to suggest that the VS Package is not getting initialized, though it is clearly installed. What am I missing? In case it's relevant, [here](https://github.com/janos-ss/vs2015-vsix-cannot-debug/blob/master/VSIXProject4/VSPackage1.cs)'s the source code of the VS Package, and [here](https://github.com/janos-ss/vs2015-vsix-cannot-debug)'s the entire dummy project.

If you need more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> VSPackages are loaded into Visual Studio only when their functionality
>   is required. For example, a VSPackage is loaded when Visual Studio
>   uses a project factory or a service that the VSPackage implements.
>   This feature is called delayed loading, which is used whenever
>   possible to improve performance.

To automatially load a package on VS startup, you typically add a ProvideAutoLoad attribute to your main package class.

See [Loading VSPackages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166762.aspx) documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the other answer here, the solution to the OP's actual problem is:

Just ignore the message and don't worry about it.  The symbols aren't loaded *right now*, but they'll be loaded by the time the breakpoint is ready to be hit.